Is it possible to mount a virtual drive with custom read / write functions
I'm wondering if the following is possible on Windows, make a program (like python for example), that mounts a drive like S:\ and inside that drive, the data is purely controled by the program. The mount is not based of an existing folder in the pc, or a virtual disk from a .vhd file. It's the programs that tells the pc the read / write results.
An example of that could be just to have a .vhd, and access it from a mounted drive, but the pc doesn't have direct access to the file, the programs does and act as a middlepoint between the two. The idea being to apply encryption for example so only the program can read the virtual disk file and the user can access it live on a mount point.
Is this somewhat possible ?
I tried stuff with FUSE and for Windows winfsp, but I couldn't find anything to specifically control the read write actions, I also tried win32 python module with kernel stuff but same, I managed to mount ghost drives or that refuses to load.

"is possible on Windows, make a program (like python for example), that mounts a drive like S:\ and inside that drive, the data is purely controled by the program" - Sure, you can write a custom driver.

could be a solution yes, is it the simplest one ? it seems rather complicated but if that's the only one I'll take it I guess
